# cast to unsigned need very long

Tags: mysql

I've the following problem:

i want to query some data from 3 big SQL-Tables.

eintraege ~13000 rows // rubrik2eintrag ~ 9500 rows // rubriken ~ 425 rows

This query

```
SELECT eintraege.id AS id, eintraege.email, eintraege.eintrags_name, eintraege.telefon, 
    eintraege.typ, rubrik2eintrag.rubrik AS rubrik, eintraege.status,
    IFNULL( GROUP_CONCAT( rubriken.bezeichnung ), \'- Keine Rubrik zugeordnet\' ) AS rubrikname
        FROM eintraege
        LEFT OUTER JOIN rubrik2eintrag ON rubrik2eintrag.eintrag = eintraege.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN rubriken ON rubrik = rubriken.rubrik_id
        GROUP BY id
        ORDER BY `id` DESC
        LIMIT 0, 50
```

works fine for me (~ 2 seconds response time) but the entrys appear not in the correct order. (e.g. the row with the id 500 came right before the row with id 3000 )

so i cast the id to unsigned. like this:

```
ORDER BY  CAST(`id` AS UNSIGNED) DESC
```

But now the query needs nearly 40 seconds. 
Is there a better/faster way to reach a correct ordered output?

Comment: What do you get from `desc <query>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, `id` is not defined as integer (or numeric) datatype. That would explain the ordering, where it's ordering by string value.

Some possibilities:

Introduce a new column in the table with integer datatype, populate/maintain the contents of that column, add an appropriate index with that column as the leading index, and change the query to order by the new column.  (That would be the best MySQL approximation of a function based index.)

Or, store the string value with leading zeros, so they are the same length.

```
000000000500
000000030000
```

Or, redefine the `id` column to be integer type.

Aside from those ideas... no, there's really no getting around a `Using filesort` operation to order the rows by integer value.